# This c program skips the scanf(); command and has errors with switch case

Tags: c, switch-statement, scanf

This program was coded to complete one of my university lab-sheets. I don't know how to modify the `scanf()` statement to correct this error. 
It seems there is an error with the switch-case too. This is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

//Function main
int main (void)
{
    char roomType,payingMethod,cont;
    int noOfRooms=0,noOfNights=0;
    float discount=0,amount=0;

    while(cont!='n'||cont!='N')
    {
        printf("\n(D-Deluxe|S-Superior Deluxe|C-Club Suits|E-Executive Suits|P-Presidential Suits)\nENTER THE ROOM TYPE:");
        scanf("%c%*c",&roomType);

        if(roomType!='D' || roomType!='S' || roomType!='E' || roomType!='C' || roomType!='P')
        {
            printf("Invalid Room Type!\n");
            return 0;
        }

        printf("\nENTER THE NUMBER OF ROOMS:");
        scanf("%d",&noOfRooms);
        printf("\nNUMBER OF NIGHTS:");
        scanf("%d",&noOfNights);
        printf("\nPAYING METHOD (M-cash|C-credit card):");
        scanf("%c%*c",&payingMethod);

        if(payingMethod=='c'||payingMethod=='C')
            discount=0.9;
        else 
            discount=1.0;

        switch(roomType)
        {
        case 'D':
            amount=31000*noOfRooms*noOfNights*discount;
            break;

        case 'S':
            amount=35000*noOfRooms*noOfNights*discount;
            break;

        case 'C':
        case 'c': 
            amount=50000*noOfRooms*noOfNights*discount;
            break;

        case 'E':
        case 'e': 
            amount=75000*noOfRooms*noOfNights*discount;
            break;

        case 'P':
        case 'p': 
            amount=100000*noOfRooms*noOfNights*discount;
            break;

        }

        printf("\nTotal amount payable: %f\n",amount);

        printf("\nDO you want to continue(y/n):");
        scanf("%*c%c",&cont);
        printf("__________________________________________________________");
    }

}//End function main
```

Comment: It does not get the char inputs

Comment: Put a blank before the `%c`.  Twice.  The blank reads the newline left behind by `%d`.  This is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with the inputs. You have a wrong if condition there
it must be

`if(roomType!='D' && roomType!='S' && roomType!='E' && roomType!='C' && roomType!='P')`

because everytime you give a roomType is not all of them `D, S, E, C, P` so your if condition evaluates to true everytime. You need to use `&&` instead of `||` so that if its one of them then it evaluates to false.

Dry run of if condition in the question `if(roomType!='D' || roomType!='S' || roomType!='E' || roomType!='C' || roomType!='P')`

If I give input as `D`,
then `roomType!='D'` evaluates to false so it jumps to the next check i.e.

`roomType!='S'` so now my roomType is `D` and not `S`, so this condition falls true and it goes inside the `if condition` and exits the code. This happens everytime so this code never works.

All it need is to modify its `if condition`

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather assume that you can read the *return value* section of [the `fscanf` manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html#tag_16_170_04), and write some debugging code to:

- **ensure that `scanf` is returning the *correct* value**, and...
- **inspect the contents of `roomType`, `payingMethod` and `cont` after you read them** (hint: they *might* be newlines, which would appear *invisible* on your console when you attempt to print them as characters; so *print them as integers instead*)...

... than assume that you *can't* read that manual and fix the problem for you...

---

In addition to *that* error, there's a logic error in the termination of your loop. Your loop will run until `cond` is not equal to `'n'` *or* `cond` is not equal to `'N'`; this is semantically different to when `cond` isn't contained within the set of `['n', 'N']`.

- When `cond == 'n'`, `cond != 'N'` so the loop keeps running.
- When `cond == 'N'`, `cond != 'n'` so the loop keeps running.

In other words, you have an infinite loop. You probably meant `while (cond != 'n' && cond != 'N')` or better yet, `while (!strchr("nN", cond))`...

A similar problem presents itself in `if(roomType!='D' || roomType!='S' || roomType!='E' || roomType!='C' || roomType!='P')`. You probably meant to use `&&`, or you could use `if (!strchr("DSECP", roomType))`...

Answer (score 0):

There is wrong if condition instead of using || (or) you have to use &&(and ) because in many cases the if condition become unnecessarily true and return 0 executed and the program get ended with no output.
Also use case 'd' and case 's'  other than this switch case is perfect .
Let's have a dry run of your code
In first let's say that if user enter 'S'
So roomType='S' now we go to if condition with this value
In if roomType!='D' becomes true and as in  ||  expression if any condition is true the result is true so if condition become true and print output Invalid Room Type! and program end by return statement.